# CMSIS-RTOS osThreadId to integer type

Tags: c, rtos, cmsis

I'm porting a product to a CMSIS-based RTOS, and the product needs to obtain the thread ID as a 32-bit integer. However, the CMSIS thread id type (`osThreadId`) is completely opaque, typedef'd to `struct os_thread_cb *` with a comment that it can safely be changed to something else as.

So is there a safe device-independent way to get a thread-unique integer id? Can I assume, for example, that the pointer address itself will be unique and constant for each thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`osThreadId` is a pointer - pointers on Cortex-M are 32 bit, so casting to an 32 bit integer type is safe.  As it is a pointer it the thread's *control block*, it will be entirely unique to that thread.

Since you are using CMSIS, it rather implies that target architecture, but in the general case to ensure portability to systems with perhaps different sized pointers, you could use `uintptr_t` declared in *stdint.h*.  A typedef may be useful:

```
typedef uintptr_t tid_t
```

Then you can safely cast an `osThreadId` to a `tid_t` - either implicitly or explicitly.

Strictly `uintptr_t` is an integer type capable of holding a `void*` such that casting back to a `void*` it will compare as equal to the original pointer. Since any pointer type may be cast to and from `void*`, it is generally the case that a `uintptr_t` can hold any pointer, however if such things worry you, you could strictly cast to a `void*` before assigning to a `uintptr_t` - but in practice this is probably unnecessary and certainly so on Cortex-M.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Yes, I think Cortex-M architecture is a safe assumption for the port code (this is for all ARM mbed-compatible devices). I don't have the option of using a uintptr instead of uint32, so I'm glad to hear pointers are always 32-bit for Cortex-M.

Comment: One clarification though: can I safely assume that the osThreadId pointer returned by osThreadGetId() is always the same for a given thread? Intuitively I would think so, but the documentation doesn't make me certain.

Comment: It wouldn't be much of a thread ID if that were not the case, so I think you can assume that to be the case regardless of any explicitly statement in the documentation.